# Connect a Mac to Apple TV to test tvOS app

Tags: mac, tv, usb-c

I’m a developer working on a tvOS app and I need to test it on the actual device. From what I've read I would need a USB-C (male) to USB-A (male) cable in order to connect the device to the Mac.

Is there any other way to accomplish the connection and test the app? Can this be done via wireless? Or do I have to have the aforementioned cable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode there should be simulator you can use. You would need to connect the cable to TV to test on the App on the Apple TV its self